# What is the equivalent of returning an object with only a post-link function?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

In the [Angular JS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) for $compile it is stated:

> A compile function can have a return value which can be either a
>   function or an object.
>
> returning a (post-link) function - is equivalent to registering the
>   linking function via the link property of the config object when the
>   compile function is empty.
>
> returning an object with function(s) registered via pre and post
>   properties - allows you to control when a linking function should be
>   called during the linking phase. See info about pre-linking and
>   post-linking functions below.

**Based** on [The nitty-gritty of compile and link functions inside AngularJS directives](http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/#) as an example of a compile function returning an **object**:

```
function createDirective(name){  
  return function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      compile: function(tElem, tAttrs){
        console.log(name + ': compile');
        return {
          post: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){
            console.log(name + ': post link');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My interpretation of the documentation is that returning a **function** is allowed and it's assumed to be a the post-link function, i.e. the following is equivalent:

```
function createDirective(name){  
      return function() {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          compile: function(tElem, tAttrs){
            console.log(name + ': compile');
            return function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){
                console.log(name + ': post link');
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the definition provided, this would be the equivalent:

```
function createDirective(name){  
    return function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

As stated in the definition, returning post link is same as link only when compile is empty... so there is link property above. You can see that the function signature is even same, just different variable names.

Comment: I can see the same [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) states: _A compile function can have a return value which can be either a function or an object._ Which is exactly what you've stated. Thank you.

Comment: I've never used an object as the return myself, but maybe it has a use.